# Read custom configuration section which is having same nested element

Tags: c#, .net, xml, configuration, web-config

Want to create the custom configuration section where I need to read the same nested element.

If you see in the below sample XML, the **setting** element can repeat to the nested level.

Would any body please tell me that how would I **define the entity** to read this kind of nested structure where nested element name is also same?

Note: Please make sure that the I need to read the collection of the same nested element which can be repeated multiple times. E.g. 'setting'

```
<customConfigSection>
    <setting source="">
        <setting from="web1" to="web2" source="" />
        <setting from="web3" to="web4" source="" />
        <setting from="web5" to="web5" source="" />
        <setting from="web7" to="web6" source="" />
        <setting from="domain2" to="" source="">
            <setting from="web1" to="web2" source="" />
            <setting from="web1" to="web2" source="" />
            <setting from="web1" to="web2" source="" />
        </setting>
    <setting>
<customConfigSection>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using **ConfigurationSection**:

```
public class SomeSettings : ConfigurationSection
{
    private SomeSettings() { }

    [ConfigurationProperty("FillColor", DefaultValue="Cyan")]
    public System.Drawing.Color FillColor
    {
        get { return (System.Drawing.Color)this["FillColor"]; }
        set { this["FillColor"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("TextSize", DefaultValue="8.5")]
    public float TextSize
    {
        get { return (float)this["TextSize"]; }
        set { this["TextSize"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("FillOpacity", DefaultValue="40")]
    public byte FillOpacity
    {
        get { return (byte)this["FillOpacity"]; }
        set { this["FillOpacity"] = value; }
    }
}
```

web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="SomeSettings" type="MyApp.SomeSettings, SomeSettings" />
  </configSections>
  <SomeSettings FillColor="LightBlue" TextSize="9.5" FillOpacity="50" />
</configuration>
```

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32490/Custom-Configuration-Sections-for-Lazy-Coders) is full article in Code Project

Comment: Thanks, but this question is regarding to read the same nested element collection.

Comment: There is an example there I think that describe this too.

Comment: No, the example mentioned there doesn't suit for my requirement.